# How do I import mixins using `pyjade` efficiently?

Tags: python, templates, pug, jinja2, pyjade

Referring to https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/pyjade/issues/27, it seems the jinja2 does not allow importing mixins from external files.

However, I got a helper.jade which has loads of mixins. If I need to use many different mixins from one file, does it mean I have to do it like:

```
- from 'helper.jade' import mixin_a, mixin_b, mixin_c, mixin_d...

mixin mixin_a(var1, var2, var3)
  div blah blah blah
```

which the import statement is rather inefficient.

Is there a better way for doing it. For example, similar to the following syntax?

```
- import 'helper.jade' as h

mixin h.mixin_a(var1, var2, var3)
  div blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a somewhat ugly workaround I found in a newer version of pyjade solves this: [Including mixins in pyjade workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278199/including-mixins-in-pyjade-workaround/27278200)