# Including mixins in pyjade workaround

Tags: pyjade

As mentioned in the github issue [#70](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/pyjade/issues/70) including mixins aren't supported.

Are there any good workarounds or alternative solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pyjade's implementation of include doesn't support mixins, but ["extends"](http://jade-lang.com/reference/extends/) does, although you have to use a "block". So what you could do if you just need to import one file:

```
extends mixins.jade
block layout
  +link("example", "http://example.com/")
```

mixins.jade:

```
mixin link(text, url)
  a(href=url)= text

block layout
```

(Answering my own question, because I searched hard before figuring this out myself and thought it could be helpful to others)

Comment: Does it work with multiple extensions? E.g., mixins.jade -> base.jade -> my_template.jade.

Comment: Yes. That's how I have things set up now. You have to use another block of course. If anyone knows a better way please let me know.